# Dual RegularExpressionValidators on 1 control, still does postback?

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, web-applications

I have 3 filter textboxes on my asp.net page. Each textbox is assigned 2 regularexpressionvalidators to them, 1 for numeric and 1 for alpha. It detects the validations correctly but when i press my search button, it still postback even when the validation tooltip appears(showing the filter is invalid). Any ideas why its "ignoring" the validation and posting back anyways? Here is my definition of the 3 controls and their validations.

```
<td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAcctFilter" runat="server" BackColor="#FF6600" TabIndex="1">Enter Account No</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revAcctFilter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtAcctFilter"
                    ToolTip="Enter Valid Account" ValidationExpression="^\d*$" ValidationGroup="Numeric"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revAcctFilter2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAcctFilter"
                    ValidationExpression="^Enter Account No$" ValidationGroup="Alpha"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtYearFilter" runat="server" BackColor="#FF6600" TabIndex="2"> Enter Year</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevYearFilter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtYearFilter"
                    ToolTip="Enter Valid Year" ValidationExpression="^20\d{2}$" ValidationGroup="Numeric"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevYearFilter2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtYearFilter"
                    ValidationExpression="^Enter Year$" ValidationGroup="Alpha"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthFilter" runat="server" BackColor="#FF6600" TabIndex="3">Enter Month</asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevMonthFilter" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtMonthFilter"
                    ToolTip="Enter Valid Month" ValidationExpression="^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])$" ValidationGroup="Numeric"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevMonthFilter2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMonthFilter"
                    ValidationExpression="^Enter Month$" ValidationGroup="Alpha"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
```

Comment: That depends on 2 or more things: the validationGroup on your button was not set, or the input passed the regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidationExpression="^Enter Account No$|^\d+$"  is the correct answer for this. I had to use the ^ $ tags for each side of the | to make it validate both sides. This allowed me to go back to just one expression. I also added the causesvalidation for each control to prevent a postback. So far its working :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `CausesValidation` is not set on your search button.  You might check that.

Incidentally, if you have two contradictory regular expressions that you want the content of each textbox to meet, you might not ever be able to submit, because both can't be satisfied at the same time (except by an empty string).